# how to import in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, import

I am trying to import "react-dropdowns-datepicker" and "react" in the following code however it doesn't work:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
</head>

import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from'react-dropdowns-datepicker';

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

class Main extends React.Component{
    render() {return (<div>asdf</div>)}
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Main/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

</script>
</body>
```

what is the correct way to do this? Thanks

PS: I have attempted the change you mentioned,

I tried this:

```
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

class Main extends React.Component{
    render() {return (<div>asdf</div>)}
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Main/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

</script>
</body>
```

Here is the error:

```
react-datepicker.js:4850 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactOnclickoutside2.default) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (react-datepicker.js:4850)
    at __webpack_require__ (react-datepicker.js:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (react-datepicker.js:648)
    at __webpack_require__ (react-datepicker.js:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (react-datepicker.js:63)
    at __webpack_require__ (react-datepicker.js:30)
    at react-datepicker.js:50
    at react-datepicker.js:53
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (react-datepicker.js:9)
    at react-datepicker.js:10
(anonymous) @ react-datepicker.js:4850
__webpack_require__ @ react-datepicker.js:30
(anonymous) @ react-datepicker.js:648
__webpack_require__ @ react-datepicker.js:30
(anonymous) @ react-datepicker.js:63
__webpack_require__ @ react-datepicker.js:30
(anonymous) @ react-datepicker.js:50
(anonymous) @ react-datepicker.js:53
webpackUniversalModuleDefinition @ react-datepicker.js:9
(anonymous) @ react-datepicker.js:10
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, just saw your update. In the future, you can send notifications by using the @ sign and mentioning my name in a comment

Comment: Did you look at the CodePen I referenced below? That has a working date picker on it and uses React :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on using `react-dropdowns-datepicker`, use these links:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-onclickoutside@5.7.1/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-datepicker/0.37.0/react-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Check out [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/jochenberger/pen/xRpQOK) for an example.

Note that the order is important here as these three are dependent of each other.

In the end your code should look something like the following:

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-onclickoutside@5.7.1/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-datepicker/0.37.0/react-datepicker.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

<!-- ... the rest of your code continues on here ...-->
```